# Javascript Making Sure Object & Object Property are Defined

Tags: javascript

I'm often verifying whether javascript objects are defined and specific properties for that object are also defined.  Currently I do it like this:

```
var output = {

        listings: [
            {title: "First Listing"}, 
            {title: "Second Listing"}, 
            {title: "Third Listing"}
        ]
    }


if ( typeof output !== "undefined" && output.hasOwnProperty('listings') ) {

        // do something
}
```

Is there a better or shorter way to handle the verification that the object and property are defined?

Comment: Depends. Do you know that `output` will be an object and `listings` will  be an array if defined? I so, then do `if (output && output.listings)`

Comment: `typeof output === "object"` may be better. And possibly `Array.isArray(output.listings)`. It all depends.

Comment: @Xotic750: `typeof null` returns `"object"`. Since he want's an array on the `listings` property of the object, he can safely exclude all falsey values.

Comment: @squint True, my comment wasn't very precise.

Comment: I guess if I needed to be completely sure, I would have to also confirm that output is an object and that output.listings are an array e.g. (typeof output !== "undefined" && typeof output === "object" && output.hasOwnProperty('listings') && output.listings.constructor === Array)

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the truthiness of output and output.listings. If a variable is not null and is not undefined its truthiness is true.

```
if (output && output.listings) {
//do something
}
```